# Codeigniter. How to decorate dates taken from DB in loop (in VIEW )

Tags: codeigniter, date, model-view-controller, explode

This is my first question on this site, so i really have been searching much for answer.
I'm making a site with some events (trainings and internships) and have some links to look for:

- Future events;
- Current events;
- Past events;

So, these are not categories, but are dynamic and made in a such way (for example, "Future events"):

Trainings_Controller:

```
public function future()
{
$this->load->model('trainings_model');
$data['settings'] = $this->trainings_model->get_trainings_list('future');
$this->load->view('trainings_list_view',$data);
}
```

Trainings_Model:

```
function get_trainings_list($time)
    {
        $date = date('Y-m-d'); 
        switch($time) {
            case 'future':
                $this->db->where('start_date >', $date);
            break;
            case 'current':
                $this->db->where('start_date <', $date);
                $this->db->where('end_date >', $date);
            break;
            case 'past':
                $this->db->where('end_date <', $date);
            break;
        }
        $this->db->where('category','1');
        $query = $this->db->get('trainings');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And how it looks in loops in VIEWS now (i have purposely written all this mess in my view just to show you what i need it to look like), and MY QUESTION IS:

**How to make it all clean and right.**

```
<!-- Event Listing -->
<?php foreach ($settings as $item):
$format_start_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item['start_date']));
$format_end_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item['end_date']));
$format_cal_date = date('j/M', strtotime($item['start_date']));
$cal_date = explode('/', $format_cal_date);?>
    <div class='evlist'>
        <div class='evdate'>
            <span class='day'><?=$cal_date[0];?></span>
            <span class='month'><?=$cal_date[1];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class='evdesc'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>'>
                    <img src='<?=base_url();?><?=$item['img_path'];?>' width='113' height='82' alt='' />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='desc'>
                <h4 class='bold'>
                <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>'>
                    <?=$item['name_ru'];?>
                </a></h4>
                <p><?=$item['short_desc_ru'];?></p>
                <div class='evdet'>
                    <span>Сроки проведения: <?=$format_start_date;?> - <?=$format_end_date;?> | </span>
                    <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>' class='more txthover'>Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

*Please, any ideas?*

Comment: please note that base_url takes parameters, so you can make your code a little bit nicer with this: `<?=base_url('trainings/view_training/id/' . $item['id'])?>`, please also make sure that you check before each "foreach" that you can loop thru object/array so `if (empty($settings))...`  basically that is all I can add.

Comment: Thank you for this, but i'm interested mostly on how to move this part: <?php foreach ($settings as $item):
`$format_start_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item['start_date']));
$format_end_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($item['end_date']));
$format_cal_date = date('j/M', strtotime($item['start_date']));
$cal_date = explode('/', $format_cal_date);?>` from View to Controller or Model, and DO I REALLY need to do it while useing MVC?

Comment: I see the problem. Ill craft you an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after comment I see what you have trouble with.

please edit `return` line in your model to this one

`return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result_array() : FALSE;`

so whenever you have 0 results it returns (boolean) FALSE and it is easy to work with

edit your controller so it looks like

```
public function future() {
    $this->load->model('trainings_model');
    $data['settings'] = $this->trainings_model->get_trainings_list('future');
    if ($data['settings'] === FALSE) return 0; //no results or make something here that prevents looping in foreach
    foreach ($data['settings'] as $setting_key => $setting) {
        //now grab code that you want to move from view and put it here ;)
        $data['settings'][$setting_key]['format_start_date'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($setting['start_date']));
        $data['settings'][$setting_key]['format_end_date'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($setting['end_date']));
        $data['settings'][$setting_key]['cal_date'] = explode('/', date('j/M', strtotime($setting['start_date'])));

    }

    $this->load->view('trainings_list_view',$data);
}
```

and now your view file edit, you do not need to check $settings if it is set because we took care about it in controller by if/else statement

```
<?php foreach ($settings as $item): ?>
    <div class='evlist'>
        <div class='evdate'>
            <span class='day'><?=$item['cal_date'][0];?></span>
            <span class='month'><?=$item['cal_date'][1];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class='evdesc'>
            <div class='thumb'>
                <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>'>
                    <img src='<?=base_url();?><?=$item['img_path'];?>' width='113' height='82' alt='' />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='desc'>
                <h4 class='bold'>
                <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>'>
                    <?=$item['name_ru'];?>
                </a></h4>
                <p><?=$item['short_desc_ru'];?></p>
                <div class='evdet'>
                    <span>Сроки проведения: <?=$item['format_start_date'];?> - <?=$item['format_end_date'];?> | </span>
                    <a href='<?=base_url();?>trainings/view_training/id=<?=$item['id'];?>' class='more txthover'>Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Wow! It looks just like as I wished it to be! I'm gonna test it tonight, but I'm sure it will work. The only thing I doubt is this line: `$data['settings'][$setting_key]['cal_date'] = explode('/', $format_cal_date);`. I'll comment wheather it works tomorrow. So sorry I have no enough reputation to vote for your answer. Thank you much!

Comment: no problem, if it works just accept answer if not we will figure it out, have agood one

Comment: So :) Start_ End_date are displayed properly, but I have some trouble with format_cal_date and cal_date. First of all I have the next php Notice: `Message: Undefined variable: format_cal_date`. That's sure because we have no variable `$format_cal_date`. I tried to hand it by myself for the whole day changing it into some arrays we have, but still no way :( By the way, is it ok to change your solution into: `$val['start_date'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($val['start_date']));` instead of `$data['settings'][$setting_key]['format_start_date'] = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($setting['start_date']));`?

Comment: And this line is just magic: `$data['settings'][$setting_key]['cal_date'] = explode('/', date('j/M', strtotime($setting['start_date'])));` Did'nt know I can act like that. Thank you VERY much!!! Can you plz update my changes in your code so everyone could see a properly working script?

Comment: yes you can nest functions as you wish :) btw: it was always as you wrote `<span class='day'><?=$item['cal_date'][0];?></span>
            <span class='month'><?=$item['cal_date'][1];?></span>` no edit needed.